# How to add reference to Microsoft.CSharp in a Visual Studio Professional 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have inherited a Visual Studio (VB) project. (I am new to Visual Studio, Net Framework and VB). I need to add Credit Card payment processing using BeanStream. As per the instructions provided on http://developer.beanstream.com/, I tried to install Beanstream package using NuGet Package Manager Console.

```
PM> Install-Package Beanstream
```

It installed the package successfully but then rolled back and displayed an error message:

```
Install-Package: Failed to add refernece to 'Microsoft.CSharp'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

I understand that Micsosoft.CSharp is either not installed on my Windows PC or is not accessible to Visual Studio. I did not find 'Microsoft.CSharp' in the Add Reference dialog box.

Could someone please advise how to fix this issue?

Comment: I just added the Beanstream 1.1.2 package to a VB.NET WinForms project without issue. There was no indication that it required a reference to Microsoft.CSharp and it would be bizarre if it did.  Something is up on your machine or with your project or your IDE I think.

Comment: When I tried to install Beanstream to a new project, it worked fine. However, it does not install in the existing project.

Comment: If you modify your VS installation from "Add/Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features" (you didn't mention the OS version) you might find that the C# language isn't installed. If so, install it. You might need to check for updates afterwards too.